# Piecewise linear plot with custom grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I try to plot a piecewise linear interpolation of a function w on a grid \xn={x1,x2,...,xN} using tikz. I tried using a foreach loop and store the grid as a vector to do that, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8] 
\pgfkeys{ /pgf/declare function={
   w(\x)=-.5+\x*\x*\x-\x+\x*\x;} 
}
\def \xn {-1.8,-1,-.5,.1,.9,1}; %% grid
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{
   \draw({\xn(\i)},{w(\xn(\i))})--({\xn({\i+1})},{w(\xn({\i+1}))});
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is how the output should look like (without the axes).

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to directly access the `\xn` array instead of indexing into it:

[image]

### Notes:

- I would recommend getting used to using `(\x)` instead of `\x` in function computations as it can sometimes make a difference.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8] 
\pgfkeys{ /pgf/declare function={
   w(\x)=-.5+(\x)*(\x)*(\x)-(\x)+(\x)*(\x);} 
}
\def \xn {-1.8,-1,-.5,.1,.9,1}; %% grid
\draw [ultra thick, blue] (-1.8,{w(-1.8)})
    \foreach \i in \xn {
       --(\i,{w(\i)})
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) can help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
          ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,
          ylabel=$I(w)x$,xlabel=$x$]
\addplot[samples at={-1.8,-1,-.5,.1,.9,1}] {.5+x^3-x+x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I have compiling issues for this code: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/axis lines' and I am goin
g to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: @GregordeCillia Is that the first error you get? Maybe you don't have `pgfplots` installed.

Comment: I get 2 errors: /pfgplots/compat and /tikz/axis lines don't seem to work. This is what i get [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dajacskqvlhi5pt/piecewiselin1.jpeg)

Comment: @GregordeCillia Your pgfplots version is probably old. Change the line to `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`

Comment: I get similar errors and the same outputs when I change line 3: pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/compat' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

Comment: @GregordeCillia Are you adding `\usepackage{pgfplots}` ?